# Spring AOP with bean scanned using mybatis.spring.*.MapperScan

Tags: spring, aop, mybatis, spring-aop, spring-mybatis

I am working on one component to achieve audit using Spring AOP. I could use it for most of the service's methods. But found that with Mybatis mappers AOP point-cuts don't work.

Basically, Spring AOP only works with Spring-managed beans. But these mapper beans have been scanned using `mybatis.spring.*.MapperScan` and can be autowired in other Spring components.

**Why can these beans not be scanned for Spring AOP? Any idea?**

I can use AspectJ but was keen to find out how `mybatis.spring.*.MapperScan` works.

for example -

I have these configurations one for Mybatis mapper scan and other config for application specific configurations.

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan("com.test.mapper")
public class ProviderConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(final DataSource src) throws Exception {
      ...
   }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class MainConfiguration {

}
```

My Dao logic where i call mapper method -

```
@Component
public class TestDao {

   //injecting mybatis mapper here
   @Inject
   private SaveTableData saveTableData;

   public TableData save(TableData tableData) {
       saveTableData.updateTableData(tableData);
   }
}
```

I have registered my pointcuts as below

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class TestAdvices {
  @Pointcut("execution(* com.test.mapper.SaveTableData.updateTableData(*))") 
  public void commonSaveTableData(TableData tableData) {
  }

  @Pointcut("execution(* com.test.service.CreateTableData.createTableData(*))") 
  public void commonCreateTableData(TableData tableData) {
  }  

  //advices
  @After("commonSaveTableData(tableData)")
  public void addHistoryWhenSaveTableData(TableData tableData) throws Throwable {
      //do stuff    
  }

  //advices
  @After("commonCreateTableData(tableData)")
  public void addHistoryWhenCreateTableData(TableData tableData) throws Throwable {
      //do stuff    
  }
}
```

Issue is `commonCreateTableData` which is on service method works as expected. But `commonSaveTableData` which is on Mybatis mapper method does't get invoke.

**Question is if i can autowire these Mappers in any Spring bean why can't Spring AOP intercept method call using these pointcuts?**

Comment: I have updated the question with the example.

Comment: Can you add the Service Code - or wherever you make the call to the mapper?

Comment: its fairly simple call from my Dao class. i have updated it.

Comment: Everything in the configuration looks good so far. Can you also show advices associated with the defined pointcuts?

Comment: Have added sample implementation for advices but it does not even get invoke with mapper mathods

Comment: i think you should upload all the code to github, so i can help you much

Comment: is it a typo? **Crate**TableData -> **Create**TableData

Comment: yes. corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your pointcut expression is not correct, try this

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class TestAdvices {
  @Pointcut("execution(* com.test.mapper.SaveTableData.updateTableData(*)) && args(tableData)", argNames="tableData") 
  public void commonSaveTableData(TableData tableData) {
  }



//advices
  @After("commonSaveTableData(tableData)", argNames="tableData")
  public void addHistoryWhenSaveTableData(TableData tableData) throws Throwable {
      //do stuff    
  }
//...
}
```

Comment: tried this for Mapper methods. didnt work. i can update my code.

Comment: how can you judge that the after method is not executed

Comment: I have verified this by debugging. it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't cut into the mapper like this is that when mapper is scanned by mybatis, it's bean definition has bean changed in a way that its interface is still the mapper interface but its class has been changed to MapperFactoryBean